# Recombining set elements with no duplicated pairing of elements

Tags: co.combinatorics, prime-numbers

This question arises from a request for an algorithm to do such, [from 9 sets of 12 elements, arrange 12 groups of the 9 elements, selecting 1 element from each set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334415/from-9-sets-of-12-elements-arrange-12-groups-of-the-9-elements-selecting-1-ele)

Given a set, $S$, of sets, $S_i$, $\mid S\mid = s$ where:

$\forall S_i \in S, \mid  S_i\mid = e$, all sets in $S$ have the same cardinality, $e$, and $e > 1$

$\forall S_i, S_j \in S, S_i \cap S_j = \phi, i \ne j$, all sets in $S$ are pairwise disjoint

By choosing one element from each $S_i \in S$ create a new set $C_k$, and hence $\mid C_k\mid = s$.

Let $P_k = \{ \{c_p, c_q\} : c_p, c_q \in C_k, p \ne q \}$, $P$ is the set of binary subsets of $C$.

Do there exist $C_k, k = 1$ to $se$ such that $l, m = 1$ to $se$, $P_l \cap P_m = \phi, l \ne m$?

My conjecture is that for the $se$ sets, $C_k$, to exist, then necessarily $s \le e$ and $e$ is prime.

How might this be proved, or disproved (if there is no readily findable counter example)?

Apologies in advance if this is a known result.  If so, please provide a reference. (It has been a very long time since I have done any formal math and I am a very bit "rusty".)

[EDIT - CORRECTION]
$e$ needs to be prime, not $s$ - corrected above

Comment: $C_k$ does not depend on $k$. $k$ is just a distinguisher for the $C$s, ie, $\mid \{ C_1, .., C_{se} \} \mid = se$

Comment: In essence this is a design problem to select $se$ vectors from $\mathbb{Z}_e^s$ such that the minimum Hamming distance is $s-1$. The Singleton bound requires $s \le e$, which answers half of the question.

Comment: The edited question has easy counterexamples: take $s=2$, then $P_k = \{C_k\}$ so you can take all $e^2$ possible $C_k$. This gives a counterexample for any composite $e$.

Comment: For $s=4$, a pair of mutually orthogonal $e \times e$ Latin squares allows the construction of a solution, so the existence of $4 \times 4$ Graeco-Latin squares gives a counter-example to both the original and the corrected question with $s=e=4$. Using a compact notation we can take the $S_i$ to be `0123 4567 89AB CDEF` and e.g. $C_k$ as `048C 059D 06AE 07BF 149F 158E 16BD 17AC 24AD 25BC 268F 279E 34BE 35AF 369C 378D`.

Comment: I'd say this problem is more about codes than designs. Essentially it asks for $e$-ary code of length $s$ and distance $s-1$.

Comment: Does Hall's Marriage Theorem come into this?

Comment: @Peter Taylor You have essentially answered the question, as written, in your comments. I realise that I have asked a more general question than I set out to do, and the information you have provided should allow me to develop an alternative, working solution to the initial request in Stack Exchange, the populating of the $C_k$s using cyclic rotation of the indexes to the elements of the $S_i$s to select the elements. If you could collate your comments into an answer I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: The question, I was thinking of, when I wrote this question, was as per the strategy in the initial Stack Exchange posting, the populating of the $C_k$s using artithmetic progessions, modulo e, of the indexes to the elements of the $S_i$s to select the elements.  This is still an open question, and I still think this will only work if e is prime.  I will pose this as another question. From an algorithmic point of view in terms of programming, I think it will still be useful to know the answer.

Comment: @gerry-myerson If I understand HMT correctly then the family $S$ above does satisfy HMT, since the $S_i$ are mutually disjoint and $\forall S_i \in S, \mid S_i\mid = e \gt 1$ hence $\forall G \subseteq S, \mid \bigcup S_i, S_i \in G \mid = \mid G \mid e > \mid G \mid$.  I am still looking at the generated family $C = \{ C_k \}$.  I am not sure though how to identify if there are cases where $C$ cannot satisfy HMT and even if so exactly how it will help.  Similarly, while  Peter Taylor "deconstructively" answered my question, I am still working on how to "resconstructively" apply it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\Sigma$ be an set of cardinality $e$. Then this problem is equivalent to selecting $se$ vectors from $\Sigma^s$ such that the minimum Hamming distance is $s−1$. (To see this, take $S_i = \{i\} \times \Sigma$). We could also phrase it as $\Sigma$ being an alphabet of cardinality $s$ and selecting $se$ words of length $s$ over the alphabet such that the minimum Hamming distance is $s−1$.

The [Singleton bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_bound) on cardinalities of sets of words with a minimum Hamming distance requires $s \le e$, which answers half of the question.

So since we can assume that $s \le e$, it's interesting to address the more restrictive problem of selecting $e^2$ words of length $s$ with minimum Hamming distance $s-1$. This is equivalent to finding $s-2$ [mutually orthogonal Latin squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutually_orthogonal_Latin_squares): label both the cells and the rows and columns of the Latin squares with $\Sigma$. Note in particular the construction for finite fields which gives solutions when $e$ is a prime power.